# Subtracting the last value in a group from previous values in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data

```
data = tribble(~t,~key,~value,
        1,"a",10,
        2,"a",20,
        3,"a",30,
        1,"b",100,
        2,"b",200,
        3,"b",300,
        1,"c",1000,
        2,"c",2000,
        3,"c",3000)
```

and would like to get the following result

```
result = tribble(~t,~key,~value,
        1,"a",-20,
        2,"a",-10,
        3,"a",0,
        1,"b",-200,
        2,"b",-100,
        3,"b",0,
        1,"c",-2000,
        2,"c",-3000,
        3,"c",0)
```

The idea is that I would like to subtract the 3rd value from all of the other values in that group. I tried to `group_by` the `key`, but struggled on the row wise subtraction within the group

Comment: How about `data %>% group_by(key) %>% mutate(value = value - last(value))`

Comment: that worked! thanks

Answer (score 6):

We can use the `last` function from the `dplyr`. The `arrange` function is to make sure your dataset are in the right order.

```
library(dplyr)
data2 <- data %>%
  arrange(key, t) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(value = value - last(value)) %>%
  ungroup()
data2
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#       t   key value
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1     1     a   -20
# 2     2     a   -10
# 3     3     a     0
# 4     1     b  -200
# 5     2     b  -100
# 6     3     b     0
# 7     1     c -2000
# 8     2     c -1000
# 9     3     c     0
```